# Plural form of movie titles

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, titles

When referring to the plural of a movie title (in the case where the movie has sequels), do you have to obey the pluralization rules of the last word in the title, or do you just add *-s* or *-es* to the end? For example, if I wanted to watch each of *The Matrix* movies, would I say, "Let's watch *The Matrixes*" or "Let's watch *The Matrices*?" The latter sounds kind of silly, but is it proper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's best to avoid changing the movie title at all; it should be left intact as the author intended it to be.  In your example, I'd paraphrase, and say:

*Let's watch The Matrix movies!*

or,

*Let's watch The Matrix trilogy!*

Comment: makes sense, I'm not sure why I didn't consider this. Thanks

Comment: Seems like the best way out. Although, really, let's just stop watching after the *first* movie, right, folks?

Comment: Matrix Trilogy?  There only was one surely?

Comment: Not sure whether you're joking but in case you're not, there were 2 sequels to *The Matrix*: *The Matrix Reloaded* and *The Matrix Revolutions*.  These form a trilogy.  :-)

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/566/)

Comment: Or, if you're old, it's *The Matrix*'s

Answer (score 3):

Steven Pinker is a linguist and psychologist who studies this type of question -- how words or compound phrases do, or don't, keep the irregularity of their parts.  The essentials are captured in his paper ["Words and Rules,"](http://pinker.wjh.harvard.edu/articles/papers/Edinburgh.pdf).

Pinker gives several examples to show how irregular forms (like "matrices" as the plural of "matrix") are kept in compound forms that extend the meaning of the rightmost morpheme:  grandchildren not grandchilds, overate not overeated, etc.  They are dropped when the compound form (or in this case phrase) does not mean a specialization of the rightmost morpheme:  Mickey Mouses not Mickey Mice, Walkmans not Walkmen, Toronto Maple Leafs not Toronto Maple Leaves.  Because grandchildren are children and overeating is eating, but Mickey Mouse isn't a mouse, a Walkman isn't a man, and a Toronto Maple Leaf is not a leaf.

Referring to *The Matrixes* is correct if for some reason you wanted to do that.  But it is certainly less clunky to refer to *The Matrix* movies.

Comment: This may be a digression, but is *The Matrix* series correct? I was listening to the radio the other day and I heard the host referred to *Mad Max: Fury Road* as *the latest installment of the Mad Max series*

Comment: … except Mickey Mouse **is** a mouse, and _Walkmen_ is quite commonly used, too. Indeed, to some people, like me, _Walkmans_ is utterly bizarre and actually ungrammatical. Similarly with _Batman_: the movies would be the _Batmans_ (Michael Keaton starred in the first two _Batmans_), but the characters would be _Batmen_ (there are several different Batmen in the Marvel Universe).

Comment: @RexYuan:  yes, that's fine.  _The Matrix_ is a noun modifier of "series."

Comment: The kind of Mickey Mouse you can have more than one of, though, isn't a mouse.  Two actors in Mickey Mouse costume; two Mickey Mouse cartoons; these are actors and cartoons, not mice.  If you had Mickey Mouse and his clone in a show, maybe, but... six-year-old Julia Child and her clone would not be "the Julia Children," because "Child" here means last name, not her age.  The man in "Batman" does mean "man," so of course a couple of Batman heroes are Batmen, as suggested above.

Comment: If you believe Walkmans is ungrammatical and Walkmen is right, please cite a source.  Sony has given its view.  The plural of Walkman, they say, is something like "Sony Walkman Personal Stereo Systems."